# How do trait cards work in Evolution?

Tags: evolution-origin

1. During Phase 3 when playing trait cards, the rules state a player may discard one or more trait cards.  Can a player just remove traits or must he replace traits?  *Example*: Player one has three trait cards on one species, one of them being 'carnivore'. Can that player choose to discard the carnivore card and become a vegetarian? Or must he replace carnivore with another trait?  Or can you even replace or remove the carnivore trait?
2. Can you have a long neck carnivore? Or does carnivore negate the long neck?
3. When changing a trait card, must you reveal what card you will be replacing immediately or do you reveal your traits and then determine what you will be replacing?

Answer (score 2):

### Can a player just remove traits or must he replace traits.

Yes, they can. While the original rules didn't allow this, the most recent rules allows one to remove any number of traits from any number of creatures in the Play a Trait step.

> **Play a Trait**
>
> A player may place a Trait Card **facedown** above one of his species.  A species may not have any duplicate Trait Cards and may not have more than 3 Trait Cards. A player may discard one or more Trait Cards from any of his species at this time.

---

### Can you have a longneck carnivore?

Yes, but the *Long Neck* has no effect.

> Carnivores may never take Plant Food, even with other traits such as *Long Neck*, *Cooperation*, or *Foraging*.

---

### Do you inform what card you will be replacing immediately or do you reveal your traits and then determine what you will be replacing?

Before the next player starts playing cards.

The original version of the rules made it crystal clear that the discard must happen before you play the Trait Card facedown. The updated rules are a little laxer. Discarding Trait Cards is done as part of playing Trait Cards, and you must be done this before the next player starts doing the same.

> Starting with the First Player, a player may play as many Trait Cards as he wants, or save them for the next round. There are three things a player can do (in any order) with each Trait Card when it is his turn.

Comment: Your Play a trait quote explains better than the Version 2 Rules on the PDF download of rules from the makers web site.  Thanks.

Comment: Revised my answer with respect to the updated rules. This changes the answer to the first question.